Ross Elementary Analysis Theorem 11.2 proof
The following is part of a proof for theorem 11.2 in Ross's Elementary Analysis.
Let $(s_n)$ be a sequence and $t \in \mathbb{R}$. In the proof, we assume that
\begin{equation}
\{n \in \mathbb{N} : t - \epsilon < s_n < t \} \text{is infinite for all $\epsilon > 0$.}
\tag{1}\label{1} 
\end{equation}
Now we are trying to prove by construction that a subsequence with a limit exists. We select $n_1$ such that $t-1 < s_{n_1} < t$. Then we suppose that $n_1 < n_2 < \ldots < n_{k-1}$, and
\begin{equation}
\max \{s_{n_{j-1}}, t - \frac{1}{j}\} \leq s_{n_j} < t \quad \text{for $j = 2, \ldots, k-1$}
\tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation}
The proof states that if we use (\ref{1}) by setting $\epsilon = \max \{s_{n_{k-1}}, t - \frac{1}{k}\}$, we can select $n_k > n_{k-1}$ satisfying equation (\ref{2}).
I am unsure how this choice of $\epsilon$ satisfies equation (\ref{2}). Could someone help explain this?

Ross has slipped up in his definition of $\ \epsilon\ $.  What he really wants to do is to select $\ \epsilon\ $ so that
$$
\max\left\{s_{n_{k-1}},t-\frac{1}{k}\right\}=\color{red}{t-\epsilon}\ .
$$
Thus, as acknowledged in the errata sheet for the book, the definition of $\ \epsilon\ $ should be
\begin{align}
\epsilon&\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}t-\max\left\{s_{n_{k-1}},t-\frac{1}{k}\right\}\\
\Bigg(&=\min\left\{t-s_{n_{k-1}},\frac{1}{k}\right\}\Bigg)\ .
\end{align}
